# How to use JwtBearer to authenticate SignalR client and map into cookie hub?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, signalr

Basically i know how a jwt token work. But i overwhelming with tutorial to work with my case. I works on application that use web server as gui. So I need multiple scheme authenticate, one is cookie for web client. the other is signalr client application. My approach, first client signalr connect to signalr server and execute Authentication method to check database to compare and to create claim. After that server sent jwt token to client. I read so many tutorial, it split the hub. ex, web client map into /webclient,  console client map into /consoleclient but i want both client that connect from webserver and client that connect from console join into same hub. So i can group both client that have same credential into user group. ex. console client with username Admin, and web client with username Admin will be group to User group. I assume, web cookie authentication is working now. the problem only this, add other schema to handle external client signalr.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "SID";
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => 
    {
        
    });

app.MapHub<SocketHub>("/socket");
```

Hub

```
public class SocketHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() 
            => Console.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId));
    }

    public Task Authentication(string username, string password)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bearer-token-authentication